# How to use insert_job

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to run a Bigquery SQL query using insert method.
I ran the following code just like so:

```
JobConfigurationQuery = Google::Apis::BigqueryV2::JobConfigurationQuery
bq = Google::Apis::BigqueryV2::BigqueryService.new

scopes = [Google::Apis::BigqueryV2::AUTH_BIGQUERY]
bq.authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(scopes)
bq.authorization.fetch_access_token!

query_config = {query: "select colA from [dataset.table]"}
qr = JobConfigurationQuery.new(configuration:{query: query_config})
bq.insert_job(projectId, qr)
```

and I got an error as below:

```
Caught error invalid: Job configuration must contain exactly one job-specific configuration object (e.g., query, load, extract, spreadsheetExtract), but there were 0:
```

Please let me know how to use the insert_job method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what client library you're using, but insert_job probably takes a `JobConfiguration`.  You should create one of those and set the `query` parameter to equal your `JobConfigurationQuery` you've created.

This is necessary because you can insert various jobs (load, copy, extract) with different types of configurations to this one API method, and they all take a single configuration type with a subfield that specifies which type and details about the job to insert.

More info from BigQuery's documentation:

- [jobs.insert documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert)
- [job resource: note the "configuration" field and its "query" subfield](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#resource)